# Pass reference of parent object on click of button located on related object

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object A and related custom object B. I have put a button on related object B. When I press this button, I show a visualforce page that contains a grid of table data with checkboxes and a process button. Upon clicking this process button, I do some processing which requires data from the Parent Object A.
How can i pass data or reference of object A in the custom VF page of Object B and use it in cotroller class of object B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access a parent object through the lookup field on the child object. For example on the child object `B__c` there should be some lookup field `A__c` that referenced the object `A`. So you could access all fields of the object A from object B using field `A__r.SomeField__c`

For more information read the topic [Salesforce Relationship Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)